# using RegCreateKeyEx gives error code 5

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, registry

I used RegCreateKeyEx from a win32 application(VisualStudio 2008) in 64 bit windows(Project built with target x64). It was able to create a registry entry. Now I have a dll file (Project built with target x64) which too wanna create registry entry but my dll is returning error code 5(Yeah! its a sign of access denied). My **samDesired** flag have **KEY_ALL_Access** + In linker->manifestfile->run as administrator chosen which still fails with error code 5. Whereas it works perfectly in 32bit windows(Project built with target x86). Am i missing something?
**NOTE:** I'm trying to create an entry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: When you say "registry entry" do you mean a registry key or a registry value?

Comment: @HarryJohnston i meant registry key.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` because this isn't a hive.  You need to put your key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` or (less probably) one of the other hives.

I don't know why this appeared to work when you were running 32-bit code in WOW64, perhaps this is a side-effect of the way the 32-bit view of the registry is presented.